# SpeechRecognition on chromium not working between 8pm and 3am

Tags: javascript, webkit, chromium, voice-recognition, webkitspeechrecognition

**First some context :**

I have an orange pie (sort of raspberry pi 3) running on ARM so I can't install the real chrome.

I have a Node.js app who is running on chromium, the voice recognition is client side. The voice recognition works great except between 8pm and 3am. The app runs all day long every day.

**Some code :**

```
  var init = function (sandBox) {
        _sandbox = sandBox;
        _recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
        // Are we processing a short phrase or performing continuous dictation?
        _recognition.continuous = true;
        // Do we require interim results in addition to the final results?
        //_recognition.interimResults = true;

        _recognition.lang = 'fr-FR';
        // Kick off the Speech to Text recognition process
        _recognition.start();
        notify('start recording');
        // Set up 
        _recognition.onstart = function (event) {
            if (_deaf) {
                return;
            }

        };
        _recognition.onerror = function (event) {
           // console.log("onerror", event);
            /*
             _recognition.stop();

             setTimeout(function () {
             _recognition.start();
             }, 1000);
             */
        };
        // Process parsed result
        _recognition.onresult = function (event) {
            notify('display bottom', 'listen : '+event.results[event.results.length - 1][event.results[event.results.length - 1].length - 1].transcript );
            if (_deaf) {
                return;
            }

            if (+event.results[event.results.length - 1][event.results[event.results.length - 1].length - 1].confidence > 0.5) {
                _sandbox.notifyServer('speakable', event.results[event.results.length - 1][event.results[event.results.length - 1].length - 1].transcript);

            }
        };
        // Housekeeping after success or failed parsing
        _recognition.onend = function () {

            try {
                _recognition.start();
            } catch (e) {
                //console.info(e); 
                // do nothing
            }
        };
        /*

         setInterval(function () {
         try {
         _recognition.stop();
         setTimeout(function () {
         _recognition.start();
         }, 1000);
         } catch (e) {
         //console.info(e); 
         // do nothing
         }
         }, 5000);*/
    };
```

**Error :**

I'm receiving a network error. But this doesnt make any sense the network is running fine.

**Question :**
Why ? Seriously why it works great except when I really want to use it ? Closing the browser and turning it back on doesnt seem to help. Around 3am it works again..... This issue is driving me crazy.

Comment: The hours don't quite fit, but are you certain your service provider isn't throttling your connection speeds? Have you tried placing timing logging between functions, to check the network connection isn't timing out due to a client process taking too long, rather than actual network latency itself - you mentioned it ran continuously, so I wonder if there's a memory bottleneck issue. Finally, perhaps set up a ping check to http://connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204 between those hours and log to see if they are also slower? All I can think of! I hate frustrating and nonsensical issues...

Comment: One more thought - You're not exceeding any kind of usage limit by 8pm, which zeros again at 3am?

Comment: @brandall Every 20 minutes or so I check the connectivity status, the internet speed and the latency. It's not perfect (around 5Mb) but it's working fine. I think the trouble is because of quotas after a long search I discover that google is now selling the speechApi if you don't use chrome. I think that's pretty much it.

Comment: you must be using a Chromium api that has a usage limit, so you can only use it in a few hours

Comment: @Dorathoto yea I now use an x86 with chrome and it works fine.